# Xcode Swift - Modifying subview properties

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am using this function to create some navigation buttons.

```
func create(size:CGFloat, y:CGFloat, button:Dictionary<String, String>) -> UIButton {
    // setup size variables
    let width = size;

    var height = size;
    if button["position"] == "top" || button["position"] == "bottom" {
        height = size+1;
    }

    var marginTop:CGFloat = 1
    if button["position"] == "top" {
        marginTop = 0
    }

    // create button
    let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width-width, y*size, width, height))

    // background image
    let bgImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, marginTop, width, height-2))
    bgImage.image = UIImage(named: "nav-bg.png")

    // background image active
    var bgImageActive = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, marginTop, width, height-2))
    bgImageActive.image = UIImage(named: button["bg-active"]!)
    bgImageActive.hidden = true
    bgImageActive.alpha = 0

    // button icon
    let iconImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, marginTop, width, height-2))
    iconImage.image = UIImage(named: button["icon"]!)

    // button label
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, height-35, width-20, 30))
    label.text = button["name"]!
    label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    label.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 10)
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    label.numberOfLines = 2

    // add subviews
    btn.addSubview(bgImage)
    btn.addSubview(bgImageActive)
    btn.addSubview(iconImage)
    btn.addSubview(label)

    return btn
}

var btn = create(navBtnSize, y: CGFloat(i), button: navButtonSettings[i])
btn.addTarget(self, action: "navBtnTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

func navBtnTapped(sender:UIButton) {
    // change button subview properties
}
```

How do I set the "bgImageActive" subview to be not hidden when I tap the button? Since the buttons are created from the function I can't call the ImageView by name.

I tried:

```
sender.subviews[1].hidden = false
```

But that results in the error:

```
'AnyObject' does not have a member named hidden.
```

I can't figure out how to modify the subview properties.

I figured I could also try to tag the UIImageView and call:

```
bgImageActive.tag = 1
~
sender.viewWithTag(1).hidden = false
```

But that didn't work either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
(sender.subviews[1] as UIImageView).hidden = false
```

And the problem was, that the subviews array stores AnyObjects, and Anyobject doesn't have a hidden property, so you have to cast it in order the have that property.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I figured I would have to cast it as UIImageView, but I didn't realise that I would need to wrap it in parentheses like that to do it, since normally you cast at the end.